# Can this seasonal cottage be insulated for winter use?

Tags: plumbing, winterizing

I really love this summer cottage.  However, I want to use it year round to get the most value.

It is in Maine (where it gets cold).

It sits on top on blocks and the well water is let in and the waste is led out to a septic system.

Before I give up, is there a way to convert it for winter use (even just for weekends)?

Some thoughts I had: Seal up the crawl space, massive amounts of insulation, foam the pipes and/or electric heat the pipes have GC concrete the dirt floor.

[image: No foundation]

Comment: That's not what the term "winterized" means in my part of the world. Here it means "for storage", as in boats and seasonal cabins. You'd winterize this place to close it up for winter. Sounds like you're asking about _insulating_.

Comment: And to answer properly we'd need more information about the structure, septic lines, etc. You've left things quite vague, so the only answer is "those things sound reasonable".

Comment: Yes, insulating for use.

Comment: I will get more info and post...

Comment: Of course there is a way.  The only question is can you afford it?

Comment: A well maintain/used septic system should okay.  Water lines must be kept above 32 degrees, either by burying them deep(4+ feet) or by keeping the area they in above freezing(24/7 heat).  Good insulation keeps the heat cost down.

Answer (score 3):

Verify first that the property is not restricted to seasonal use only, whether outright, or via means that you may not have considered such as the roads are not plowed in winter, but if you want to hike in or use a snowmobile the town does not mind.

After that it's just money to make things happen, and choosing option of how things happen, and how much money that takes.

On the high end, you jack it up and put a full foundation/basement below frost line (insulate that on the OUTSIDE for best results) - on the low end you insulate and heat tape your water and sewer lines until they ae below frost line (and you hope they actually get there in some reasonable distance) and insulate everywhere else in the structure, including under the floor in that case (well, you should insulate under the (basement) floor in the case that you add a full basement, too.) Of course, you might have rock before you get to frost line, and you get to make choices about how you handle that as well.

You'll need heating capacity it probably does not have at present.

Doing all this will probably raise your taxes on it, as it becomes worth more.

But really, it's just applied money.

Comment: How does one "insulate and heat tape water and sewer lines until they are below the frost line"? Does the insulation add so much weight they just sink into the ground? :D

Comment: Town probably wants the driveway passable for first responders.  You may be ok hiking in, but EMTs not so much.

Comment: You dig a hole around the pipes, apply heat tape from the bottom of the hole to the point of entry into the building, apply insulation around that, and refill the hole. Same as any mobile home sewer and water in a cold climate.